# How to make work Wordpress wp_nav_menu with Jquery Ui Tabs

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to make work Jquery UI tabs in Wordpress, I added how look's my basic HTML doc and WordPress menu atm. Where do I need to include those ID's  '#tabs-1'

index.html

```
<ul class="menu-nav">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Your Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Another Title</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Wp index.php file

```
 <ul class="menu-nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write an own navwalker class. As an example you can take this here: [Bootstrap Navwalker for Wordpress](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker). Don't forget to require it once in your `functions.php`.